# не работает Deep link android

Tags: java, android, android-adb

Хочу добавить `Deep Link` в свое приложение, вроде делаю все как [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters) описано, но при тесте выдает ошибку.

Вот пример моего `intent-filter` и ошибка которую я получаю при тесте. Где мною была допущена ошибка?

**Манифест:**

```
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.имя_компании.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/имя_проекта" />
            <data android:scheme="имя_компании"
                android:host="имя_проэкта" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Запускаю так:**

```
C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\название проэкта> adb shell am start  -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "имя_компании://название_проэкта"
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=имя_компании://название_проэкта }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.actio
n.VIEW dat=имя_компании://название_проэкта flg=0x10000000 }
```

Comment: Добавьте ещё инфы. Как именно тест запускаете?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну через cmd из папки проэкта(от имени администратора), или вы не про это?

Comment: [Попробуйте](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21035826/3212712) одиночную кавычку перед `am` и в самом конце команды.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал в таком формате команды как я писал добавить кавычки и попробовал прописать команду в формате по вашей ссылке - не сработало! Мож я еще где то ошибку допустил?

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть каждый `data` тег в отдельный `intent-filter`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб зделал, но ошибка таже. может как то изменить формат команды?

Comment: Может быть... Других идей у меня нет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  все получилось запустив команду в таком формате  adb shell am start  -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d шттп://www.company.com/project_name

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

проблема была устранена изминением формата команды  и разделением одного `intent-filter` на два отдельных с разными `data`

**С**

```
adb shell am start  -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "company_name://project_name"
```

что соответствовало схеме

```
   <data android:scheme="company_name"
     android:host="project_name"
     android:path="/"/>
```

**На**

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.company.com/project_name
```

что соответствует схеме

```
<data android:scheme="http"
 android:host="www.company.com"
 android:pathPrefix="/project_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Судя по всему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585875/2893248) нельзя указывать в `<intent-filter>` больше одного `<data>` если у них 2 и больше атрибутов (или если разное количество атрибутов, точно не понял). Точнее указать то можете, и при сборки ничего ругаться не будет, но использоваться будет только один `<data>`, скорее всего последний. Так что в вашем случае надо разделить `<intent-filter>` с диплинками на два:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.имя_компании.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/имя_проекта" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="имя_компании"
            android:host="имя_проэкта" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

К сожалению не смог найти подробное описание как комбинируются несколько `<data>` в одном `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: я их  разделил, но фильтр с '<data android:scheme="имя_компании"
            android:host="имя_проэкта" />' все равно не работает, работает только первый вариант.